# How to prevent "Do you want the application foo to block incoming connections?" popup from command line

Tags: command-line, firewall

As a developer, I run a testsuite of some self-compiled binaries which try to listen on some ports on startup. This causes a barrage of popups "Do you want the application foo to block incoming connections?" as the binary is started and restarted numerous times in parallel. I want to avoid this without turning off the firewall.

Based on socketfilterfw man page the following should work:

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --blockapp /path/to/binary
```

yet it does not, even though

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --listapps
```

shows its path with "( Block incoming connections )"

Is there a way to block those popups with socketfilterfw or any tool, without disabling the firewall? The set of binary paths to be blocked is changing all the time, although it could match some regexp or shell glob.

Thank you